# Error running tests with flutter : "Failed to load "_test.dart": Shell subprocess ended cleanly. Did main() call exit()?"

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

Whenever I add new tests to my codebase I encounter the aforementioned error message while running them.

```
package:flutter_tools/src/test/flutter_tester_device.dart 224:73  FlutterTesterTestDevice.finished
===== asynchronous gap ===========================
dart:async/future.dart                                            Future.any.onValue
Failed to load "app/test/club/club_section_test.dart": Shell subprocess ended cleanly. Did main() call exit()?
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

##### TLDR

```sh
flutter clean && flutter packages get
```

#### Workaround

Well it seems that for some reason flutter is caching some data that becomes stale, you can easily get the test back by running:

```sh
flutter clean
```

Which "Delete the build/ and .dart_tool/ directories"
and then:

```sh
flutter packages get
```

To rebuild those directories and download dependencies.

Comment: Yes this temporarily solves the problem but it keeps happening over and over again, wheras it didn't used to happen. Having to `flutter clean` and refetch packages every time I want to run my tests isn't practical. There must be some underlying problem that is causing this to happen in the first place that isn't being solved.

Comment: Agree @ActionJackBarker , this was **just** a workaround I found and wanted to share. Don't know if this is already being looked into in the flutter repo.